# making a textview viewable when clicked

Tags: java, android

i was wondering how can i make a textview viewable where the user can click on it and when he click on it the textview creates another page where the text is by her own and the user can select the textview now, because i have more than 30 textviews and i want to make each of them when they get clicked they have their own layout where user can select them now and add more stuff like sharing the textview and this is all in one layout for each textview alone

i hope you can help me and thanks in advance

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: according to your first sentence it seems, it is already viewable and user click on it, please clear first that after which component clicked it will viewable

Answer (score 0):

Make a new activity and use put/get extra to pass on data to new activity.
try following
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to make your TextView visible on  click event

```
myTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create list view
and in on item click of the list you can simply start another activity which will have layout according to the item you have clicked.
click [here](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/)

and there onitemclick you can start new activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
    intent.purStringExtra("key",rowItems.get(position));
    startActivity(intent);

try it and ask if you have any doubt or it is not clear

Answer (score 0):

try using Buttons instead of TextViews for getting TextViews...
example
you have Buttons "A" and "B" and want to show Button "B" only when when A Clicked and then want to show TextView "C" only when when B Clicked
in this way (A->B->C )
then try using these codes:

only important parts are written...
in activity_main.xml :

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/button_A"
 android:onClick="do_A"/>

<Button
 android:id="@+id/button_B"
 android:onClick="do_B"/>

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/Textview_C" />
```

in MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button A = findViewById(R.id.button_A);
Button B = findViewById(R.id.button_B);
TextView C = findViewById(R.id.Textview_C);

B.setVisibility(View.GONE);
C.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
public void do_A (View v){
B.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
public void do_B (View v){
C.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
```

Comment: but when i click the button it will show a button i want them to show a textview